# Delete row in quip spreadsheet

Tags: python, quip

Is there a way that we can delete a row from quip spreadsheet using quipclient. The same way, can we add a column or a row to quip spreadsheet using quipclient??

Thank you!

I want to delete certain rows from my quip spreadsheet on each code run. If that's not possible, atleast create a new spreadsheet to add the data that I need.